# How to send system properties using AWS device farm Jenkins plugin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-device-farm

I have few system properties that my test framework use during running the automation. When I execute my tests using command line I use below command -

```
mvn -DPLATFORM=ios -DDEVICE_NAME='iPhone 7' -DAPP_NAME=test -DAPP_FILE="testapp.app" -DsuiteXmlFile=testng.xml test
```

How can I pass these parameters while running the same test using the Jenkins plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Device Farm Jenkins plugin helps you to run your tests on Device Farm without going to the Device Farm console or using CLI.
Are you able to run your tests using Device Farm console. Once you are able to run your tests using Device Farm console , running throughs Jenkins is straight forward.

In DeviceFarm console, you will have to upload through app, test package , select the Device you want to run tests on. Same things can be done through the jenkins plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can add these properties by writing  them to a file using a plugin.  By placing the file in the ./src/test/resources directory we can include it in the jar and reference it in code.

Here is a video I authored explaining how to do that.

https://youtu.be/33xLa5BWbtQ